# AutoHotkey + World of Wacraft: repeated jumping

Tags: autohotkey, world-of-warcraft

I'm actually playing with `AutoHotkey`: I read [this tutorial](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Tutorial.htm#Create) and I created my first script.

It should make my character jump by pressing spacebar every 1 seconds:

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
#Warn  ; Recommended for catching common errors.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.

#ifWinActive World of Warcraft
{
    Loop
    {
        Send {Space}
        Sleep 1000
    }
}
return
```

It doesn't work: while I'm in the game nothing happens; it works fine when I'm **out** of the game (like in Notepad).

What's wrong with that?

**EDIT**: solved. If you're using Windows 7, you've to run your script with administrator privileges.

Please, moderator: delete this question, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Not to be a wet blanket, but this kind of thing violates TOS as far as user terms for WoW, aka botting paranoia on their part which really does screw up the game for others.

Comment: Hi, Celess. It's just an experiment: I'm used to play on a private server, not on the official one. Yesterday, after the macro you've read above, I played with some spell-spamming macros just to see how they worked... and to save my fingers' health a bit while playing :)

Honestly: I don't see many differences between spamming spells with mouse wheel and doing the same in that way... with the excpetion of mouse consumption, obviously.

Comment: Yeah sorry. It was the obligitory post and probably why no one touched this one. I agree. It does get a bit like splitting hairs with some in game armed to the teeth with every kind of macro for automation compared to spamming some keys.